# how to pass multiple key/value pairs in a single variable using query string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have one requirement like passing multiple values in the query string in a single variable.

> Id=(refine_1=cgid=womens&refine_2=c_refinementColor=Black&refine_3=price=(0..500))

Is it possible to accept value like above sample from the query string?if yes,please tel me how to achieve this?

Comment: concat the string not with "&" but with other syntax like "#" .Id=(refine_1=cgid=womens#refine_2=c_refinementColor=Black#refine_3=price=(0..500))

Answer (score 1):

You should URL encode it:

```
?id=(refine_1%3Dcgid%3Dwomens%26refine_2%3Dc_refinementColor%3DBlack%26refine_3%3Dprice%3D(0..500))
```

Now assuming that your controller action takes an `id` parameter:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

the value of this parameter inside the action will be `(refine_1=cgid=womens&refine_2=c_refinementColor=Black&refine_3=price=(0..500))`.

You could bring this even a step further and write a custom model binder that will parse this value and bind it to a view model containing those properties that your controller action could take as parameter instead of a `id` string parameter.